# Binding objects to targets vs using object names directly

Tags: c++, opengl

In OpenGL, when using objects, you can bind that object to a target and specify that target in a function. For many functions, there is also another version, that instead of taking a target, takes the object name directly. Example :

```
glBufferData(target, ...)
glNamedBufferData(buffer, ...)
```

So my question is, which function is faster? And are there places, where one is superior? I would assume the latter because you doesn't need to bind and maybe unbind before you can call it. I've yet to understand the meaning of using targets, but maybe there is some big advantage.

I'm using OpenGL 4.6 on Windows.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The latter function reduces the number of state changes in the driver and thus the CPU overhead of "doing graphics". If you can use direct state access functions, do it.

It is an integral part of the seminal "approaching zero driver overhead" presentation made back in 2014. [video](https://gdcvault.com/play/1020791/) [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/CassEveritt/approaching-zero-driver-overhead)

Comment: So when only using an object one time, use the latter, and when using an object multiple times in many functions, use the first. Correct?

Comment: No, the direct  access is always strictly better.